# i insert dynamically added texbox value into database in cake php

Tags: cakephp, insertion

i have the following array and i want to insert all the data along with the id i get from the last inserted id into mark table

```
Array
(
    [subjectName] => 
    [totalMarks] => 
    [marksObtain] => 
    [main] => Array
        (
            [subjectName] => physics
            [totalMarks] => 100
            [marksObtain] => 85
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [subjectName] => english
                    [totalMarks] => 100
                    [marksObtain] => 78
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [subjectName] => biology
                    [totalMarks] => 100
                    [marksObtain] => 22
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: That's nice. Good luck figuring it out. Did you have a question?

Comment: ya how to insert the data which is in the above format